# Ctrl+Space not working anywhere?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11

I need help to solve this problem which is extremely weird. This morning I was working on a project for University, and while working, I found out the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> keyboard shortcut wasn't working. At first, I thought it was a problem with the editor, but I tried other programs such as Visual Studio Code, IntelliJ, and online editors on the web and nothing worked. The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>  shortcut didn't do anything. As a programmer, it's incredibly devastating since most IDEs use this shortcut for autocompletion and I'm very used to it whenever I want to complete something. This is the only problem with the keyboard. Other shortcuts, as well as features of the keyboard itself (such as lighting, gaming mode, etc) are working perfectly fine.

I tried searching online, but couldn't find any solution. I tried uninstalling my keyboard drivers and rebooting but it had no effect. I tried updating Windows, but I am on the latest version as of now:

```
Edition Windows 11 Pro
Version 22H2
Installed on    ‎24/‎12/‎22
OS build    22621.1702
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22641.1000.0
```

I don't know what to do and I am beginning to lose it. If anyone knows how to solve this weird problem, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: at the risk of stating the obvious ... have you rebooted?

Comment: Yes. I have. I tried rebooting several times

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you have PowerToys installed, try quitting it. On my machine, I found it to be the culprit.

It is the new Peek feature of PowerToys that grabs the shortcut. You disable or change the shortcut of this part of PowerToys without losing the whole thing.

Comment: Thank you so much. Indeed, this new feature of PowerToys was blocking the shortcut.

Comment: I was noticing this with JetBrains IDEs, so I've got an answer here with steps/images to disable just the Peek feature.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76444492/1899214

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned its probably **PowerToys**.  You don't have to remove it.  You can change the default shortcut.

I have changed mine to <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.  It is not obvious where it is, so ...

[image]